# Greendao and NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: android, orm, greendao

In the process of using greendao, when the initialization time, being given:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.greenrobot.greendao.query.WhereCollector

This exception did not occur during the compilation process, and the actual error code crashed directly at run time as follows:

```
AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.luckytry.hybrid.mainapplication, PID: 4274
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.greenrobot.greendao.query.WhereCollector
     at org.greenrobot.greendao.query.QueryBuilder.<init>(QueryBuilder.java:85)
     at org.greenrobot.greendao.query.QueryBuilder.<init>(QueryBuilder.java:77)
     at org.greenrobot.greendao.query.QueryBuilder.internalCreate(QueryBuilder.java:73)
     at org.greenrobot.greendao.AbstractDao.queryBuilder(AbstractDao.java:793)
     at com.luckytry.luckylibrary.MyAplication.APPAplication.initData(APPAplication.java:132)
     at com.luckytry.luckylibrary.MyAplication.APPAplication.initDB(APPAplication.java:117)
     at com.luckytry.luckylibrary.MyAplication.APPAplication.onCreate(APPAplication.java:39)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1009)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4655)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:143)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1322)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5356)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:864)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:680)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

[image]

Comment: You have proguard activated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

-Add this dependency `compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'`

-Add `multiDexEnabled = true` in your  build.gradle app config.

-Change your extend Application "MyAplication.APPAplication" to `MultiDexApplication`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, the problem has been solved!